# setColorFilter() broken on Android 4, working on Android 5

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to flash different colours onto the screen at regular intervals (a few times per second).

To change the colours, I use `Drawable.setColorFilter(int color, Mode mode)` on the background of my main view:

- `myView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);`

For debugging purposes, I added another view that I change using  `View.setBackgroundColor(int color)`.

The **problem** is that the `setColorFilter()` calls are **working on Lollipop**, but are **broken on previous versions** (specifically Nexus 7 v4.4.4, Galaxy Nexus v4.2.1).

---

I call the colour changing code inside a `Runnable` that is triggered at regular intervals by a `Handler`.

The handler is being called on all platforms (I can see the background changes due to the debugging `setBackgroundColor()` calls).

Below is the colour cycling code:

```
Handler mHandler;
RunnableOnTick thisRunnable;
View vDebug;
View vBroken;

class RunnableOnTick implements Runnable
{
    int backgroundColor;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        color = random.nextInt(2);

        switch (color)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                backgroundColor = Color.RED;
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                backgroundColor = Color.GREEN;
                break;
            }
        }

        // this works on all platforms
        vDebug.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);

        // this works only on Lollipop
        vBroken.getBackground().setColorFilter(backgroundColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
        vBroken.invalidate();

        mHandler.postDelayed(thisRunnable, 100);
    }
}
```

---

I have tried different `PorterDuff.Mode` values - still can't get it working on Android 4.

**What is different between Android v4 and v5 that would change the way `setColorFilter()` works?**

Comment: Which `Drawable` you're using exactly? It might depend on particular implementation.

Comment: @Dmitry If I remember correctly I was just using the stock green android launcher icon as this was a proof-of-concept I threw together. In the end I used a different method and haven't looked at that app in months.

Comment: Then it was `BitmapDrawable`. Well, if you don't have the app anymore, then it's hard to find the problem now. I can certainly say that color filter was working in KitKat (you can simply try to use `tint` attribute of `ImageView` - it is backed by ColorFilter)

Comment: @Dmitry I'll see what I can pull out the repo. I am always interested to know if the bug lies with me, of a very well tested framework. Will also test the supplied answer code and comment. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Richard try below method

Answer (score 6):

Ultimately, it seems like the problem is that KitKat doesn't support using a ColorFilter (or implicitly an alpha) on a Drawable that will in turn be in a StateListDrawable. My solution was to use the same to code to construct the complex Drawable and then render that into a simple BitMapDrawable:

```
 static Drawable createDrawable(Context context, int color, boolean disabled) {
OvalShape oShape = new OvalShape();
ShapeDrawable background = new ShapeDrawable(oShape);
background.getPaint().setColor(color);

ShapeDrawable shader = new ShapeDrawable(oShape);
shader.setShaderFactory(new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
    @Override
    public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
        return new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height,
                new int[]{
                        Color.WHITE,
                        Color.GRAY,
                        Color.DKGRAY,
                        Color.BLACK
                }, null, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    }
});

Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_chat_button).mutate();
icon.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.control_tint_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

Drawable layer = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{ shader, background, icon });
layer.setAlpha(disabled ? 128 : 255);

// Note that on KitKat, setting a ColorFilter on a Drawable contained in a StateListDrawable
//  apparently doesn't work, although it does on later versions, so we have to render the colored
//  bitmap into a BitmapDrawable and then put that into the StateListDrawable
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(icon.getIntrinsicWidth(), icon.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

layer.setBounds(0, 0, layer.getIntrinsicWidth(), layer.getIntrinsicHeight());
layer.draw(canvas);

return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any reference for that statement about KitKat not supporting it?

Comment: No, i don't have any such reference but above solution is working...mark my answer up..if this helps..

Comment: Solve my problem, not only kitkat but I found that it wasn't working for API < 21, but with this workaround does. won the bounty.

Comment: This is the issue persisting for me as well in 4.4 and 4.3.1 , both Samsung devices. Unfortunately this fix doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

There's an issue in AppCompat with compound `Drawable` below API 21 that me thinks is related:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191111

The simple solution is not using drawables from XML but create them in code and then apply `setColorFilter`. That's why @Hardeep solution worked.

Fun trivia: In my case `setColorFilter` on XML-created `TextView` `drawableLeft` worked fine, but only when invoked via click handler / delayed. When invoked in `onCreate` / `onResume` etc nothing happened.

Comment: lol thanks to your fun trivia, spent almost 3 hours looking for solution, posting a delayed runnable did the trick at OnClick

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on pre-lollipop, I solved replacing:

```
vBroken.getBackground().setColorFilter(backgroundColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
```

with:

```
    Drawable d = vBroken.getBackground();
    d.setColorFilter(backgroundColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    vBroken.setBackground(d);
```

Comment: perfect solution, this must be selected as accepted one, thank you @mengoni

Answer (score 1):

For me, a ColorFilter would not be applied to a color item in a StateListDrawable.

Creating a Drawable to represent that color and using that instead in the StateListDrawable saw setColorFilter working on pre-Lollipop devices I tested.

As a side note, I made a pure white Drawable so that tinting color would be applied at full opacity.

Comment: This is the right answer. Color items can't be changed by setColorFilter and should be changed to any drawable, e.g. 1px x 1px drawables items

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried directly like this?!

```
vBroken.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255),PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to paint drawable for as many different states as you want on all android versions, you can use this helper class:

```
public class MagicDrawable extends StateListDrawable {

private Map<Integer, Integer> stateColorsMap;
private int defaultColor;

public static MagicDrawable create(Drawable drawable, int defaultColor, int pressedColor, int selectedColor){
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
    map.put(android.R.attr.state_selected, selectedColor);
    map.put(android.R.attr.state_pressed, pressedColor);

    MagicDrawable stateDrawable = new MagicDrawable(drawable, defaultColor, map);
    return stateDrawable;
}

public static MagicDrawable createSelected(Drawable drawable, int defaultColor, int selectedColor){
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
    map.put(android.R.attr.state_selected, selectedColor);

    MagicDrawable stateDrawable = new MagicDrawable(drawable, defaultColor, map);
    return stateDrawable;
}

public static MagicDrawable createPressed(Drawable drawable, int defaultColor, int pressedColor){
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
    map.put(android.R.attr.state_pressed, pressedColor);

    MagicDrawable stateDrawable = new MagicDrawable(drawable, defaultColor, map);
    return stateDrawable;
}

/**
 *  Create state list drawable programmatically - just pass drawable, default color of drawable, and Map of (state , color)
 * @param drawable resourse for icons
 * @param defaultColor color for normal state
 * @param stateColorsMap map of for ex. android.R.attr.state_pressed and ColorManager.someColor
 *
 *                        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(android.R.attr.state_pressed, ColorManager.rose);
 */
public MagicDrawable(Drawable drawable, int defaultColor, Map<Integer, Integer> stateColorsMap) {
    super();
    this.stateColorsMap = stateColorsMap;
    this.defaultColor = defaultColor;

    drawable.setColorFilter(defaultColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    if (stateColorsMap != null) {
        for (int state : stateColorsMap.keySet()) {
            addState(new int[]{state}, drawable);
        }
    }

    addState(new int[] {}, drawable);
}

@Override
protected boolean onStateChange(int[] states) {

    if (stateColorsMap == null) {
        super.setColorFilter(defaultColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        return super.onStateChange(states);
    }

    boolean colorSet = false;

    for (int state : states) {

        for (int st : stateColorsMap.keySet()){

            if (state == st) {
                super.setColorFilter(stateColorsMap.get(st), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                colorSet = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!colorSet) {
        super.setColorFilter(defaultColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }

    return super.onStateChange(states);
}

@Override
public boolean isStateful() {
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score -4):

```
/**
     * Tint / Colorise the Supplied {@code drawable} into another color of supplied {@code colorResId}
     * @param context
     * @param drawable
     * @param colorResId
     * @return
     */
    public Drawable tintThisDrawable(Context context ,Drawable drawable,@ColorRes int colorResId)
    {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        int color = res.getColor(colorResId);
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
        return drawable;
    }
```

I remember this function working somewhere in my Project. Please test this yourself.

Comment: That's almost exactly what is written in his answer

Comment: Well! now I see it ,It deals with drawables and not color. If He can use Drawable to set Background this would work.

Comment: This is exactly what he is doing. Please, read the question before answering.

Comment: This function works with KITKAT and LOLLIPOP to tint the Drawable . Tested!

Comment: Even if it works - it still does not answer the question.

Comment: The one difference I can see is that I was trying with `View.getBackground().setColorFilter()`. Perhaps there is a difference between that call, and what you are demonstrating? I will try and look into it again in the next week or so.