# Programmatically set color of shape in drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable

I'm adding an item (with an icon) to my menu like this:

```
subMenu.add(user.getName()).setIcon(R.drawable.user_bg);
```

The `user_bg` drawable layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/user_color">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="#000000"
                />
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="100dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/user"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />

</layer-list>
```

How can I programmatically change the color of the drawable (`#000000`) after adding the new item?

Answer (score 0):

Create the drawable programmatically, set its color, then set it on the menu. Something like:

```
Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
if (icon instanceOf ShapeDrawable) {
  icon.getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));
  subMenu.setIcon(icon);
}
```

Comment: What if I have a `for` loop that adds multiple items to the menu where each item has its own separate color. I added your code within my `for` loop, but it's setting the color for ALL the items as the last color set in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
int red = 102, green = 34, blue = 100;
drawable.setColorFilter(red,Mode.ADD);
drawable.setColorFilter(green,Mode.ADD);
drawable.setColorFilter(blue,Mode.ADD);
```

**NOTE:** This will remove the Tint if there any, in your drawable. 
Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717831/setcolorfilter-broken-on-android-4-working-on-android-5) as well, to get more info abot `setColorFilter()` method

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it works.

1. Obtain a reference to the drawable

   If you want to setup your drawable's color and then add the subItem

   `LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_bg);`

   *Or*

   If you want to change the color after you have already added the item

   `LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable)subMenu.getItem().getIcon()`
2. Call Drawable.Mutate()

   `drawable .Mutate();`

   For explanation, refer to item #2 of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933345/change-drawable-resource-programmatically/32933905#32933905) answer
3. Create a color drawable

   `ColorDrawable newColor = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000"));`
4. Set/reset the color

   `drawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.user_color, newColor);`
5. Redraw drawable

   `drawable.invalidateSelf();`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
Drawable mDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_drawable);
mDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED,  PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));
```

using `setColorFilter()` function we can change the color of drawable programatically.

I hope it works for you