# Change drawable resource programmatically

Tags: android

I have the following xml resource code that is a background layout for a list of card items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/kpop">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#151B54"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

My problem is that I would like to change the drawable resource programmatically

```
android:drawable="@drawable/kpop"
```

(so that each card item would have a different background image)

Any idea/tip how I can do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve that:

1. Obtain a reference to your layer-list

   `LayerDrawable layer  = (LayerDrawable)yourView.getBackground();`

   *Or*

   `LayerDrawable layer = (LayerDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(R.id.yourLayerDrawable);`
2. Create a new instance of the layer drawable internally

   `layer.Mutate();`

   Android internally caches drawables, which means that if you modify a drawable obtaind through the above method, all other drawables will be affected. To prevent that, you can call [Drawable.Mutate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate())  to tell the system to retain a separate copy of the drawable so that it won't affect the other drawables.
3. Set id for item to be modified

   `android:id="@+id/image_background"`

Like this:

```
<item
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_background" <----
    android:drawable="@drawable/kpop">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#151B54"/>
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

4. Set/reset the drawable for that item

   `layer.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.image_background, yourNewDrawable);`
5. Redraw layer

   `layer.invalidateSelf();`

Comment: would be awesome if it did work . i spent a full day on this couldnt make it work :(

Answer (score 1):

You did not post your java code .. i think it helps you.
try to use this code in your own logic.

`yourCard.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.kpop) );`

or

```
yourCard.setBackground(R.drawable.kpop);
```

code is not tested but i think it will work..  comment please to ask anything.

Comment: Background drawable is not the same thing with drawable.