# How do I get the resource ID of a built in vector drawable?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an ImageView with the attribute `app:srcCompat="?android:attr/fingerprintAuthDrawable"` defined in it's layout xml file, and this works fine.

Later on, I replace the Drawable in this ImageView with another image my program generates, using code like `imageView.setDrawable(myBitmapDrawable)`.  This works fine.

At a later time I want to replace the ImageView with the original Drawable it had when the app started, with code like `imageView.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(defaultID))`

My question is how do I find that `defaultID` that corresponds to that `app:srcCompat="?android:attr/fingerprintAuthDrawable"` attribute in the layout xml?

Comment: Why don't you just save the reference of the firstly set drawable after the layout has been created? ImageView has a method called getDrawable() that returns the current drawable of the ImageView. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#getDrawable()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change drawable resource programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933345/change-drawable-resource-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android.R.attr.fingerprintAuthDrawable`