# How to create ListView items with random color on KitKat

Tags: android, listview, svg, colors, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to create ListView with randomly generated colors on KitKat.
**The problem:** It only shows the same color for different items.
Here is my code:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_item_image_background);
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        int g = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        int b = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

        int randColor = Color.argb(255, r, g, b);

        d.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(randColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        viewHolder.ivLogoBackground.setImageDrawable(d);
```

I also tried to do it like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt(256);
int g = rand.nextInt(256);
int b = rand.nextInt(256);
```

It works well on Lollipop or higher but on KitKat it shows the same color for each item.
I think that the problem is in `d.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(randColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));`

Android M:[image: Android M]

Android KitKat:[image: KitKat]

**Solution:** `Drawable` must have `mutate()`  method. Then images in list items will be different color:)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32048294/6891637) should help.

Comment: @Ajil O Unfortunately no. My screenshot shows that the method `setColorFilter` is working. But colors not generated randomly.

Comment: What does your drawable look like?

Comment: @Ajil O It's svg in xml. And I found the problem. Originally my drawable was immutable,  so I added `d.mutate()` and now it works like a charm:)

Answer (score 0):

///Adapter class

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
private ColorGenerator generator;
private Activity mActivity;
private ArrayList<String> iDataList;
public TestAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> countryList, int limit, boolean isLiveCountry) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
    generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);
    return new CustomViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    int color = generator.getRandomColor();
    holder.view.setBackgroundColor(color);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return iDataList.size();

}
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private View view;

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.view);
    }
}
```

}

//Color Generator

```
public class ColorGenerator {
public static ColorGenerator DEFAULT;

public static ColorGenerator MATERIAL;

static {
    DEFAULT = create(Arrays.asList(
            0xfff16364,
            0xfff58559,
            0xfff9a43e,
            0xffe4c62e,
            0xff67bf74,
            0xff59a2be,
            0xff2093cd,
            0xffad62a7,
            0xff805781
    ));
    MATERIAL = create(Arrays.asList(
            0xffe57373,
            0xfff06292,
            0xffba68c8,
            0xff9575cd,
            0xff7986cb,
            0xff64b5f6,
            0xff4fc3f7,
            0xff4dd0e1,
            0xff4db6ac,
            0xff81c784,
            0xffaed581,
            0xffff8a65,
            0xffd4e157,
            0xffffd54f,
            0xffffb74d,
            0xffa1887f,
            0xff90a4ae
    ));
}

private final List<Integer> mColors;
private final Random mRandom;

public static ColorGenerator create(List<Integer> colorList) {
    return new ColorGenerator(colorList);
}

private ColorGenerator(List<Integer> colorList) {
    mColors = colorList;
    mRandom = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public int getRandomColor() {
    return mColors.get(mRandom.nextInt(mColors.size()));
}

public int getColor(Object key) {
    return mColors.get(Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % mColors.size());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: this will generate random color for each item of listview or recyleView . Thats what you asked for , right ?

Comment: This will generate random color from the list of colors. But I need to get randomly from the full range of colors. And again, this answer not working properly on KitKat.